# Setting the Value of a cell in VBA (Why wont my code work)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code

`hood.Offset(0, 2).Value = hoodName`

hood is declared as a range. The cell that makes up hood is returning a #VALUE error, and the cell I am trying to set is not returning anything. WHY?!?!?!?!? What am I doing wrong?

Alright, so here is some more code:

```
Function NhoodCheck(rXY As Range) As String
Dim hoodName As String
Dim hood As Range
Set hood = rXY.Cells(1, 2) 
If OHC(rXY) = True Then
 hoodName = "Ohio City"
End If
Set hood.Offset(0, 2).Value = hoodName
End Function
```

The basic idea is that the function is called and passed a range (rXY) then calls a boolean function as part of an if statement. If that returns as true, then it sets hoodname to the name of the neighborhood. It performs other checks if it is false, all in determining the neighborhood that a place is in. It then returns the first part of the neighborhood, but the hoodname is a larger area and goes in the cell next to the cell calling the function (hence the offset). the first part works corrctly. it just doesn't set the value of the offset cell. in this case I would want some of the cells to say "Ohio City".

Comment: It's not very clear what is "cell is not returning anything". Please, give more code and explanation.

Comment: Could you provide where does HoodName come from, what value you have on it, some more of your code and a better explanition we could work with to help you?

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
hood.Offset(0, 2).Value = "hoodName"
```

Without the `"` VBA thought that `hoodName` is a variable.

---

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()        
    Dim hood As Range        
    Set hood = Range("D4")
    hood.Offset(0, 2).Value = hoodName    
End Sub
```

It will return an error, because `hoodName` is a variable and a variable should be declared, due to the presence of `Option Explicit`. If you remove the `Option Explicit`, the code will work, because VBA will think that `hoodName` is a variable and it is equal to `""`.